# Smoothly change the images in the transitions

Tags: android, android-kenburnsview

I'm using the KenBurnsView in the login screen of my App to show several images in the background. The thing is that this images change too abruptly. Isn't a way to implement a fadein/fadeout effect when changing the transitions from one image to another, hooking somewhere in the view API?

This is the code that I'm using to implement the transitions.

```
private void setupAnimationBackground() {
    mBackgroundImageView.setTransitionListener(new KenBurnsView.TransitionListener() {
        @DrawableRes int[] mResources = new int[]{
                R.drawable.splash1, R.drawable.splash2, R.drawable.splash3,
                R.drawable.splash4, R.drawable.splash5, R.drawable.splash6
        };

        int mIndex = 0;

        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
            mIndex = (mIndex == mResources.length - 1) ? 0 : mIndex + 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
            mBackgroundImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), mResources[mIndex]));
        }
    });
}
```

mBackgroundImageView is a KenBurnsView. I have the images resources in my drawable folder. As you can see I store the references in a resource int array.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, nope. You need to have two KenBurnsViews one overlapping on top of the other and you handle the crossfading yourself.